# Laravel - In controller pass variable to one function to another

Tags: php, laravel

In controller

```
class acontroller extends Controller
{    
    private $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->variable;
    }

    public function first(){
        $calculation = 1 + 1;
        $this->variable = $calculation;
        return view('something.view');
    }

    public function second(){
        dd($this->variable);
        return view('something.view2');
    }
}
```

This is an example. 
What I'm trying to do is to pass the calculation result in first method to the second. I am expecting in second method inside dd() to show the result 2 but instead of this I am getting null.

What is going wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You really should redesign it. What you could do is create third method and do calculations in it. Then just call this method from first and second ones.

```
public function first(){
    $this->third();
    dd($this->variable);
    return view('something.view');
}

public function second(){
    $this->third();
    dd($this->variable);
    return view('something.view2');
}

public function third(){
    $calculation = 1 + 1;
    $this->variable = $calculation;
}
```

Just insert `$this->second();` right after `$this->variable = $calculation;` in the `first` method.

Comment: I cant do this it doesn't offers me the solution I want.

Comment: Well, then just try to do `$this->second();` after calculations are made.

Comment: Just insert `$this->second();` right after `$this->variable = $calculation;` in the `first` method.

Comment: No it is not working. I think is not working because it does not know what value to insert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110844/discussion-between-vasilis-greece-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use some session variable?

```
Session::put('calculation', $this->variable);
```

and

```
$value = Session::get('calculation');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling first method in one http call and the second in another one so these two are completely separate run of your application if you want to share a variable in different requests you should use some kind of database